# Default constructor c++ Random Number valid?

Tags: c++, statistics, default

I'm new to c++ and I'm not that familiar with default constructors. I'm asked to write a class called Stats and in the default constructor write a constructor that uses the Random number generator to generate sampleSize int between minValue and maxValue then store it in an array called data[]. So far whenever I've been using default constructors I would just initialize them to zero or null. I'm not sure how to write a default constructor with these set instructions so my code would run correctly without errors. Here is what I have

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stats
{
private:
    int sampleSize, minValue, maxValue;
    int data[];

public:
    Stats()
    {
        sampleSize = 0;
        minValue = 0;
        maxValue = 0;
        data[] = sampleSize;
    }
    Stats(int samleSize, int min, int max)
    {
        samplesize = samleSize;
        minValue = min;
        maxValue = max;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want `data` to hold? and what do you want to initialize it to? so that it is considered correct.

Comment: Well I want to write a constructor that uses random number to generate sampleSize integers between minValue and maxValue then store it in data, but I'm not sure on how going in writing that in a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far a I can tell you want a dynamically sized array of `int`s to be held in `data`, your current syntax is not correct but something along these lines should be what you are looking for. First `data` needs to be a `pointer`:

```
int *data;
```

and then your constructors would look something like this:

```
Stats()
{
    sampleSize = 0;
    minValue = 0;
    maxValue = 0;
    data = NULL;
}

Stats(int samleSize, int min, int max)
{
    sampleSize = samleSize;
    minValue = min;
    maxValue = max;
    data = new int[sampleSize] ;
}
```

Once you have a `pointer` in your class you need to also have a `destructor` so that you can free the memory associated with that `pointer` and it should look similar to this:

```
~Stats()
{
  if( NULL != data )
  {
     delete [] data ;
  }
}
```

This is assuming you need to stick with dynamically allocated memory for your assignment, if you are allowed to use `std::vector` then this becomes a much simpler problem, `data` becomes this:

```
 std::vector<int> data ;
```

and you do not need to worry about allocation at all and then when you need to add data to it then you just call `push_back`:

```
 data.push_back( randomNumber ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[] = sampleSize;
```

is not valid syntax in C++. You cannot initialize an array with that.

Meanwhile, `data[]` has no type. You should do

```
int data[];
```

You also need to first allocate memory for the `data` array, then try to use random number generator to put numbers into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::vector` for data. Since the size is not fixed for all instances.

```
class Stats
{
private:
    int sampleSize, minValue, maxValue;
    vector<int> data;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

public:
    Stats()
    {
        sampleSize = 0;
        minValue = 0;
        maxValue = 0;
        data.reserve(sampleSize); // Just to avoid reallocations.

    }
```